# Can I use Assert class in Junit if I am not implementing Junit test cases and how to do that?

Tags: java, junit, assert

I am implementing tests depending on private test framework, but I found no proper assert method to stop the test. So I try use Assert class in Junit. But always get below error. Is it true I can't use Assert in Junit if I am not using its framework(Run as Junit test)?

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: junit.framework.Assert
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

btw, what it should be for Junit path?

Comment: Yes, you have to put the framework (as you said) on the classpath of your project.

Comment: Yes, you can use them. From your error, I suggest you check your projects dependencies. Seems like you aren't including the junit jars in your  project's classpath.

Comment: thank you, for Junit path, where it should be?

Comment: You can use directly assert functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Hamcrest](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest) if you're looking for an assertion library.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use JUnit's Assert outside of JUnit tests.

However, you can just use Java's `assert` keyword instead.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966347/assert-vs-junit-assertions) is a comparison between the two.