# MojoFailureException AssertError using maven install

Tags: maven, mockito, maven-surefire-plugin

I wrote a unit test that passes when I run it in Eclipse, but fails when I do "maven install".

I use JUnit 4, Mockito 1.9.5, Maven 3.0.4, JRE 1.7._51, Sunfire 2.15.

The assert that seemingly fails is:

```
assert string1.equals(string2);
```

Comment: Do you want to compare the content of the strings or ensure that they are the same in the String pool?

Comment: Yes, I replaced "==" by ".equals" and it still fails.

Comment: Without further source code, I would simply say the strings are not equal.

Comment: Please post your test code.

Comment: How and where is `string1` and `string2` defined?

Comment: Sorry guys, I found the issue...
The reason it passed in Eclipse was because I was using "assert".
Using "assertEquals" or "assertTrue" solved the problem.

Comment: I am going to remove all the code and error message because it is meaningless.

Comment: Please change 'assert string1.equals(string2)' into 'assertEquals(string1, string2)'. That should give you more hints why the test fails.

Comment: `assert` will works too, but you need to enable assertions with -ea, and is not recommended for unit testing

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

Java keyword `assert` must be activated to work.

> They can be activated at run-time by way of the -ea option on the java command, but are not turned on by default.

- [What does the Java assert keyword do, and when should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758224/assertion-in-java)

### Some advices

For string comparision use `equals`

```
assert string1.equals(string2)
```

- [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Use [junit assertions](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html) in test

```
assertEquals(string1, string2)
```

- [assert vs. JUnit Assertions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966347/assert-vs-junit-assertions)

For best results use [AssertJ](http://assertj.org/) - Fluent assertions for java

```
assertThat(string1).isEqualTo(string2);
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about this... But the test still fails using maven install.

Comment: post maven version, surefire version and test code, then we can help you :)